# Getting a NULL value back for a Model when I see it is NOT NULL during debugging

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a "Details" View that I am displaying to the user to find out if any statuses are associated with any projects.

When the "GET" for the "Details" view is performed, only a dropdownlist appears asking the user to select an item from the list. In the View, I simply check if the "Model" is null to display the rest of the view or not (the associated projects for that status).

During the "POST", a "status" is retrieved with its associated 'projects'. While coming back into the View, **I am expecting the Model not to be null** (since it found a status and its associated projects).

If the Model is not null, I want to display the rest of the View.

**In the "POST", why is the Model still null**? See below code & screenshots. Please copy and paste the screenshot to your favorite image viewer for better viewing.

fyi, after looking in the browser with the debugging tool, I can see that there is **no html displayed** after the dropdownlist?????

### Model

```
namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]

    public partial class Status
    {
        public Status()
        {
            Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [DataMember]
        public short StatusID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        [DataMember]
        public string StatusDescription { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### JS

```
$.ajax({
        url: Url,
        data: JSON.stringify(status_Input),
        //data: AddAntiCSRFToken(JSON.stringify(status_Input)),
        dataType: "html",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            $('<div id="divLoadMsg" style="text-align:center"><img src="~/Content/progress.gif" /><br/><b>Please wait...</b></div>').dialog({
                modal: true, resizable: false, height: 'auto', width: 'auto', minHeight: '30px',
                open: function () { $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide(); }, close: function () { $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').show(); $(this).dialog('destroy').remove() }
            });
        },
        success: function (data, status)
        {
            if (status == "success")
            {
                // Retrieved data
            }
        },
```

### CONTROLLER

```
// GET: Statuses/StatusProjects/Details
public ActionResult Details()
{
    return View();
}

// POST: Statuses/StatusProjects/Details/5
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(short? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return View("IDIsNull");
    }

    Status status = await db.GetProjectsByStatusIDAsync(id);
    if (status == null)
    {
        return View("ObjectModelNull");
    }

    return View();
}
```

### VIEW

```
@model YeagerTechDB.Models.Status
@using YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Statuses


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Statuses";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h3>Select Status to see associated Projects</h3>

<div>
    @Html.Partial("_SelectStatusProjects", new StatusesDDL());
</div>

@if (Model != null) // Needed for GET 
{
    <div>
        <table class="table table-condensed">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Associated Projects for selected Status
                </th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="right">Project ID</th>
                <th>Project Description</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th align="right">Quote</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
                <th>Created Date</th>
                <th>Updated Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.ProjectID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Description)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Quote)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Notes)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CreatedDate)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.UpdatedDate)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

### EDIT

After making the change that Kundan suggested, I can tell during debugging, if I step through the code, it goes into the View after the POST. The Model is not null and it then properly cycles through the child records that I want displayed on the screen.

However, after that is finished, **those records are not displayed on the browser window**! The only thing that appears is the dropdownlist again **without any display beneath that.**

Nothing else is executed after the debugging of the View on the POST which is correct.

The only change that was made in this process is returning the object model of the View (status) as Kundan suggested.

**How come the records are not being displayed in the browser after the POST?**

fyi, after looking in the browser with the debugging tool, I can see that there is no html displayed after the dropdownlist?????

fyi, I also tried running the page without the dropdownlist and forcing in a value during debugging which would bring back some projects, the same way as if I had selected it from the drop down list. Even with the html removed for the dropdownlist, it went through the View cycled through the collection, but did not emit any html?

Here are the screen shots...
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Model is null because you didn't pass back it to View from your controller. The code should be like below:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(short? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return View("IDIsNull");
    }

    Status status = await db.GetProjectsByStatusIDAsync(id);
    if (status == null)
    {
        return View("ObjectModelNull");
    }

    return View(status);
}
```

This will fix your issue.